# Using DrectX and .Net

Tags: .net, winforms, architecture, directx

My company is evaluating basing an platform architecture on .Net Winform.  We need modern GUI and we also needs to render 3D graphics with C++ and DirectX.

We have the basic architecture working by passing a Winform Panel control's HWND to a C++ that renders DirectX to the HWND.

How likely is this API will continue to be exposed by Microsoft?  My understanding is that both XNA and WPF are well established.  At some level they both work on HWND
The "Winform HWND to Direct X" seems to based on API primitives.  Its not the most modern choice but should be safe from API changes for several years.

So my belief is that this a 'safe' architectural choice and not likely to get axed just because...

Comment: `My company is evaluating basing an platform architecture on .Net Winform` - winforms is not recommended for any new projects. Only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: `We need modern GUI` - winforms is incapable of that. use WPF.

Comment: HWNDs have not been the most "modern choice" for the past 29 years.  They are still fundamental to way it works and will be for many more years to come.  If you don't want a HWND then you'd need to write a Store app.

Comment: XNA is also deprecated, and no longer recommended, so your company is going very wrong way.

Comment: yes Microsoft has cease to advance winforms but it seems unlikely that they would depracate HWND anytime soon